# iphone, objective c, how to read raw data from audio file (without codec applied)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, audioqueue, raw-data

I am developing an iphone app, which sends/receives data to audio/headphone jack of iphone. I assume we can send/receive data to headphone jack but that data is audio file with some codec applied. I want to read an audio file and send raw data to headphone jack.. How can i do that..? Any help or code snippet appreciated.
Best regards,
Abdul Qavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the headphone jack is on the other side of a couple of D>A converters, I guess you'd need a codec that converts to modem tones.  Hope you files are really small 'cos transfer rate would be pretty slow, even if you could figure out how to use both channels.

Just 'tooth 'em.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: @Dear Martin: I don't want to send audio data to headphone jack. I want to send some text file to headphone jack...

Comment: Sure, I can see how this might be occasionally useful for transferring small files to a PC with no bluetooth/network connection.  You're still stuck with a 2-channel analog interface & so the bits in the file have to be converted to 'modem tones' in the iPhone and demodulated in the PC.  The analog channels have a greater bandwidth than phone lines & so you should be able to do better than the old '56k' modems, but that's the only way it can be done.  If you are going to plug the iPhone into a PC microphone jack, you will need some attenuation and an app on the PC to demodulate the signal/s.